# Setting height of column to another for each element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sadly, I need to use JS to set `col-1` (static) to the same height as a text container `col-2` (dyanmic).

I've tried:

```
$(function () {

    var article = $('section.inner-services article');

    $(article).each(function( index ) {

        var textColHeight = $('section.inner-services article .col-2').height();
        var figureCol  = $('section.inner-services article .col-1');
        $(figureCol).css('height', textColHeight);
        console.log(index);

    });

});
```

My HTML markup is (Simplified):

```
<section class="inner-services"> 
    <article> 
        <col-1> 
        <col-2> 
    </article> 
</section>
```

This does not loop through each `article` as expected and set `col-1` height to the height of `col-2`.

Please briefly explain where I have gone wrong if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, once you have created the jQuery object, there is no need to create it once again, so no need for `$(article)`.

At second inside `each` you can refer to current element as `this`.

Correct code might look like this:

```
$(function () {

    $('section.inner-services article').each(function( index ) {

        var textColHeight = $(this).find('.col-2').height();
        var figureCol  = $(this).find('.col-1').height(textColHeight);

        console.log(index);

    });

});
```

Comment: @SMacFadyen, yeah, I always forget that `this` is not a jQuery object in `each` until I get a corresponding error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look for `col-2` and `col-1` under every `article`

```
$(function () {

    var article = $('section.inner-services article');

    $(article).each(function( index ) {

        var textColHeight = $(this).children('.col-2').height();
        var figureCol  = $(this).children('.col-1');
        $(figureCol).css('height', textColHeight);
        console.log(index);

    });

});
```